# Emploi de "plate-forme indépendant"

Tags: usage, adjectifs

> C'est un logiciel **indépendant de la plate-forme** qui permet aux
>   fabricants de téléphones mobiles d'utiliser des interfaces graphiques
>   hautes performances.

Peut-on employer *plate-forme indépendant* en français comme ci-dessous :

> C'est un logiciel **plate-forme indépendant** qui permet aux
>   fabricants de téléphones mobiles d'utiliser des interfaces graphiques
>   hautes performances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non, ou le sens sera modifié. On ne peut pas calquer sur l'anglais *platform-independent*.

*Logiciel plateforme indépendant* sonnerait très "jargon informatique" et serait compris comme "logiciel qui s'assimile à une plateforme et qui est indépendant " (mais indépendant de quoi ? Cette information est perdue).

On peut par contre préciser "indépendant de toute plateforme", "indépendant d'une plateforme", etc.

Comment: Merci. C'est compris. Il me semble que sonner dans ce contexte est un anglicisme (it sounds...), n'est-ces pas ?

Comment: Hé hé... pas sûr... mais ça pourrait faire l'objet d'une question.... en tout cas, c'est un usage très courant en français.  On peut dire par exemple "C'est un nom qui sonne bien!".

Comment: Du coup, it sounds+adjectif/adverb doit être interprété par il semple+adjectif/adverb. Je l'ai appris sur FSE mais je n'arrive pas à trouver la question (ou le commentaire).

Comment: *Sonner* en français est utilisé pour donner son impression sur la qualité sonore ou phonétique d'un son, ou d'un mot voire de toute une expression, tandis que "sembler" est plus général et porte plutôt sur les apparences générales de quelque chose, quelqu'un ou d'une situation. On peut dire par exemple "quand il chante, ça sonne faux" (ou "quand Macron parle, ça sonne faux" au figuré), "tape sur le mur, ça sonne creux" (= ca donne un son qui indque qu'il y a du vide derrière la paroi) ou encore "le dernier Daft Punk sonne très disco-funk".

Comment: Je viens de poser une question sur FSE. Si tu veux, tu peux y donner ce commentaire comme réponse. Merci.

Answer (score 2):

Un logiciel *platform-independent*, ça n'existe pas vraiment, un logiciel ayant forcément des pré-requis pour pouvoir s'installer.

Une expression utilisée pour désigner les logiciels qui n'imposent pas une plate-forme particulière est :

> logiciel **multi-plate-forme** ou plus couramment **multiplateforme**.